# Copy String array from another String array returning from the function call in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to assign a String array(printHi) from another String array , returning from a function call, in Java. Here is the code for that assignment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int n = 5;
 // throws out the error        
String[] printHi = new String[] (arrayOfHiNTimes(n));

System.out.println(printHi);
}

private static String[] arrayOfHiNTimes(int n) {    

    String[] hiArray = new String[n];   
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        hiArray[i] = "hi";
    }

    return hiArray;
}
```

Comment: Start with sharing what your error message is.

Comment: It says the left-hand statement side of an assignment must be a variable.

Comment: remove the `new String[]`. You don't need to create a new array, the method `arrayOfHiNTimes()` already return an array.

Comment: String[] printHi = arrayOfHiNTimes(n) is enogh

Comment: @ Progman Thanks, I removed the String initialization and it worked. @ CeePlusPlus Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Pshemo I was trying to copy the String array values returning from arrayOfHiNTimes and assign it to printHi String array. I did have a look at the above link and tried , but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're returning the same type you're attempting to assign to the variable, there's no need to create a new array. This code should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    // throws out the error     
    String[] printHi = arrayOfHiNTimes(n);
    System.out.println(printHi);
}

private static String[] arrayOfHiNTimes(int n) {
    String[] hiArray = new String[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        hiArray[i] = "hi";
    }
    return hiArray;
}
```

If you specifically need to copy the array, then use [Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, end)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)), per below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    // throws out the error  
    /*args are the original array, the starting index (0 for beginning), 
     *and the last index + 1 since it's exclusive, which is the same as arr.length. 
     *In this case, it's the same as n since that's what you're using to determine 
     *the length of the array.
     */
    String[] printHi = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayOfHiNTimes(n), 0, n);
    System.out.println(printHi);
}

private static String[] arrayOfHiNTimes(int n) {
    String[] hiArray = new String[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        hiArray[i] = "hi";
    }
    return hiArray;
}
```